# Writing and importing custom plugins in Airflow

Tags: airflow

This is actually two questions combined into one.

My `AIRFLOW_HOME` is structured like

```
airflow
+-- dags
+-- plugins
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- hooks
        +-- __init__.py
        +-- my_hook.py
        +-- another_hook.py
    +-- operators
        +-- __init__.py
        +-- my_operator.py
        +-- another_operator.py
    +-- sensors
    +-- utils
```

I've been following astronomer.io's examples here https://github.com/airflow-plugins. My custom `operators` use my custom `hooks`, and all the imports are relative to the top level folder `plugins`.

```py
# my_operator.py
from plugins.hooks.my_hook import MyHook
```

However, when I tried moving my entire repository into the plugins folder, I get an import error after running `airflow list_dags` saying that `plugins` cannot be found.

I read up a little about it and apparently Airflow loads the plugins into its core module so they can be imported like

```py
# my_operator.py
from airflow.hooks.my_hook import MyHook
```

So I changed all the imports to read directly from `airflow.plugin_type` instead. I get another import error though, this time saying that `my_hook` cannot be found. I restart my workers, scheduler and webserver every time but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I've looked at solutions proposed in similar questions and they don't work either.

The official documentation also shows this way https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html of extending the `AirflowPlugin` class, but I'm not sure where this "interface" should reside. I would also prefer a drag and drop option.

Finally, it clearly doesn't make sense for my code repo to be the `plugins` folder itself, but if I separate them testing becomes inconvenient. Do I have to modify my Airflow configurations to point to my repo every time I run unit tests on my hooks/ops? What are the best practices for testing custom plugins?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured this out by doing some trial and error. This is the final structure of my `AIRFLOW_HOME` folder

```
airflow 
+-- dags 
+-- plugins
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- plugin_name.py
    +-- hooks
        +-- __init__.py
        +-- my_hook.py 
        +-- another_hook.py 
    +-- operators
        +-- __init__.py
        +-- my_operator.py 
        +-- another_operator.py 
    +-- sensors 
    +-- utils
```

In `plugin_name.py`, I extend the `AirflowPlugin` class

```py
# plugin_name.py

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from hooks.my_hook import *
from operators.my_operator import *
from utils.my_utils import *
# etc

class PluginName(AirflowPlugin):

    name = 'plugin_name'

    hooks = [MyHook]
    operators = [MyOperator]
    macros = [my_util_func]
```

In my custom operators which use my custom hooks, I import them like

```py
# my_operator.py

from hooks.my_hook import MyHook
```

Then in my DAG files, I can do

```py
# sample_dag.py

from airflow.operators.plugin_name import MyOperator
```

It is necessary to restart the webserver and scheduler. Took me a while to figure out.

This also facilitates testing since the imports within the custom classes are relative to the sub modules within the folder `plugins`. I wonder if I can omit the `__init__.py` file inside `plugins`, but since everything is working I didn't try doing that.

Comment: When I saw you own respond I say EUREKA !
But no... still have issue following your step.
Here my SO question (I try after that your solution). 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237543/airflow-on-docker-path-issue
Can I have your help ?

Comment: There is a typo (at least for current version of Airflow) in the code of plugin_name.py. It should be from airflow.pluginS_manager

Comment: I get "Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py] No module named 'airflow.hooks.my_plugin' "

Comment: @Julio It might be more helpful for you to start a separate question with your own setup and folder structure.

Comment: @potzenhotz the custom plugins work if I use celery executer in airflow