# Why are my custom operators not being imported into my DAG (Airflow)?

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, airflow

I am creating an ETL pipeline using `Apache Airflow` and I am trying to create generalized custom operators. There seems to be no problem with the operators but they are not being imported into my `DAG` python file.

This is my directory structure.

```
my_project\
  .env
  Pipfile
  Pipfile.lock
  .gitignore
  .venv\
  airflow\
    dags\
    logs\
    plugins\
      __init__.py
      helpers\
      operators\
        __init__.py
        data_quality.py
        load_fact.py
        load_dimension.py
        stage_redshift
```

This is what is present in the `__init__.py` file under `plugins` folder.

```
from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin

import airflow.plugins.operators as operators
import airflow.plugins.helpers as helpers

# Defining the plugin class
class SparkifyPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "sparkify_plugin"
    operators = [
        operators.StageToRedshiftOperator,
        operators.LoadFactOperator,
        operators.LoadDimensionOperator,
        operators.DataQualityOperator
    ]
    helpers = [
        helpers.SqlQueries
    ]
```

I'm importing these operators into my `DAG` file as following

```
from airflow.operators.sparkify_plugin import (StageToRedshiftOperator,
                               LoadFactOperator,
                               LoadDimensionOperator,
                               DataQualityOperator)
```

I am getting an error as follows

```
ERROR - Failed to import plugin /Users/user_name/Documents/My_Mac/Projects/sparkify_etl_sql_to_sql/airflow/plugins/operators/stage_redshift.py
```

Can you help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/57558319/6092420. However, I also suggest that you run `python __init__.py` to check for compiling errors. There may also be issues with relative imports depending on where Airflow calls your DAGs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Running the `__init__.py`  files solved most of the problem. The question you pointed to uses an additional file to register custom operators. I have managed to do this without it. I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: The additional file was not the main focus of that solution. It could be anything as long as it is inside `plugins`. The examples given even had the class in the same file as the plugins objects. I was mainly concerned about the imports and how they'd work.

Comment: The problem was with the module `__init__.py` files. Have included their content in my answer.

Comment: I believe you had the same issue as me in that your import started with `airflow` and mine started with `plugins`. What we both changed is for the import to start from the modules under the `plugins` folder, i.e. `operators` and `helpers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to register my custom operators with `Airflow` without dedicating a python file to use `AirflowPlugin` class.

I achieved this by declaring them in my `__init__.py` file under `plugins` directory.

This is how I did it.

My project folder structure is as follows

```
my_project\
  .env
  Pipfile
  Pipfile.lock
  .gitignore
  .venv\
  airflow\
    dags\
    logs\
    plugins\
      __init__.py
      helpers\
      operators\
        __init__.py
        data_quality.py
        load_fact.py
        load_dimension.py
        stage_redshift
```

My code in `plugins/__init__.py`

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin

import operators
import helpers

# Defining the plugin class
class SparkifyPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "sparkify_plugin"
    operators = [
        operators.StageToRedshiftOperator,
        operators.LoadFactOperator,
        operators.LoadDimensionOperator,
        operators.DataQualityOperator
    ]
    helpers = [
        helpers.SqlQueries
    ]
```

My code in `plugins/operators/__init__.py`

```
from operators.stage_redshift import StageToRedshiftOperator
from operators.load_fact import LoadFactOperator
from operators.load_dimension import LoadDimensionOperator
from operators.data_quality import DataQualityOperator

__all__ = [
    'StageToRedshiftOperator',
    'LoadFactOperator',
    'LoadDimensionOperator',
    'DataQualityOperator'
]
```

I am importing these custom operators in my dag file(`dags/etl.py`) as:

```
from airflow.operators.spark_plugin import LoadDimensionOperator
```

`spark_plugin` is what the `name` attribute in `SparkifyPlugin` class (stored in `plugins/__init__.py`) holds.

Airflow automatically registers these custom operators.

Hope it helps someone else in the future.

In case you are having some import errors, try running `python __init__.py` for each module as described by @absolutelydevastated. Make sure that the one in `plugins` directory runs without throwing errors.

I used `Pycharm` and it did throw me a few errors when running `__init__.py` files in the `plugins/operators` directory.
Fixing the one in `plugins` directory and ignoring the errors thrown by `plugins/operators/__init__.py` fixed my issue.

Comment: I was using `1.10.9` and `from airflow.operators.my_first_plugin import MyFirstOperator` method was working from me and now I upgraded to `2.0.1` and I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.my_first_plugin'`. Any help regarding that sir?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out: [Writing and importing custom plugins in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57558319/writing-and-importing-custom-plugins-in-airflow)

The person there was having a similar problem with their plugin, which they fixed by including a file under `airflow/plugins` named for their plugin, rather than defining it in the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I figured out a way to make airflow recognize these custom operators without creating a dedicated file in the plugins directory. I have posted it as an answer. Thank you for your help.