# Airflow on Docker - Path issue

Tags: python, docker, airflow

Working with airflow I try simple DAG work.

I wrote custom operators and other files that I want to import into the main file where the DAG logic is.

Here the folder's structure :

```
├── airflow.cfg
├── dags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── dag.py
│   └── sql_statements.sql
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── environment.yml
└── plugins
    ├── __init__.py
    └── operators
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── facts_calculator.py
        ├── has_rows.py
        └── s3_to_redshift.py
```

I setup the volume right in the `compose file` since I can see them when I log into the container's terminal.

I followed some tutorials online from where I have added some `__init__.py`.

The 2 none empty `__init__` are into

- `/plugins/operators`:

```
from operators.facts_calculator import FactsCalculatorOperator
from operators.has_rows import HasRowsOperator
from operators.s3_to_redshift import S3ToRedshiftOperator

__all__ = [
    'FactsCalculatorOperator',
    'HasRowsOperator',
    'S3ToRedshiftOperator'
]
```

- `/plugins`:

```
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin

import operators

# Defining the plugin class
class CustomPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "custom_plugin"
    # A list of class(es) derived from BaseOperator
    operators = [
        operators.FactsCalculatorOperator,
        operators.HasRowsOperator,
        operators.S3ToRedshiftOperator
    ]
    # A list of class(es) derived from BaseHook
    hooks = []
    # A list of class(es) derived from BaseExecutor
    executors = []
    # A list of references to inject into the macros namespace
    macros = []
    # A list of objects created from a class derived
    # from flask_admin.BaseView
    admin_views = []
    # A list of Blueprint object created from flask.Blueprint
    flask_blueprints = []
    # A list of menu links (flask_admin.base.MenuLink)
    menu_links = []
```

But I keep getting errors from my IDE (saying `No module named operators` or Unresolved reference operators inside the operator's `__init__`).

Since everything fails to launch on the webserver.

Any idea how to set this up ? Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: Try using just an empty `__init__.py` in the `operators` folder and do the import inside `plugins`. Alternatively, don't import from `operators`. Import directly from the file modules.

Comment: What do you mean by `do the import inside plugins`. And how do you want me to import from modules directly ?

Comment: In other words, do `from operators import *` inside the `__init__.py` in `plugins`. And define your operators like `operators = [ <file>.<operator-class> ]`. Python has annoying import logic so that might be the issue.

Comment: Could you add the error you get the the question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [puckel's](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) image?

If you are, you need to uncomment the `# - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins` lines (may there are more than one) in the docker-compose files (either Local or Celery). The rest of your setup looks fine to me.